# "Unexpected exception in route" with POST using Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded (Content-Type:application/json working fine)

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle, abstractverticle

I'm creating a post request that can except "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" using "vert.x". And getting "Unexpected exception in route
java.lang.NullPointerException" but the same request works fine when I remove the content type.

I am using vert.x 3.3.3 and trying to create a route with verticles.

````
Router router = Router.router(vertx);

```
//--- 
router.post("/sample-api").handler(new myHandler());

   // This allows post with content-type "application/json" and "Unexpected 
   // exception in route java.lang.NullPointerException" error with 
   // "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"


//---
router.route(HttpMethod.POST, "/sample-api").consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").handler(new myHandler());

   // This gives 404 on the post with content-type "application/json" and 
   // "Unexpected exception in route java.lang.NullPointerException" error 
   // with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
````

```
Error msg with content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    Unexpected exception in route java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
            at io.vertx.core.file.impl.FileSystemImpl.existsInternal(FileSystemImpl.java:772)
            at io.vertx.core.file.impl.FileSystemImpl.existsBlocking(FileSystemImpl.java:333)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl$BHandler.makeUploadDir(BodyHandlerImpl.java:141)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl$BHandler.<init>(BodyHandlerImpl.java:124)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl.handle(BodyHandlerImpl.java:65)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl.handle(BodyHandlerImpl.java:40)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteImpl.handleContext(RouteImpl.java:215)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:78)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:94)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.accept(RouterImpl.java:79)
            at io.vertx.core.http.impl.ServerConnection.handleRequest(ServerConnection.java:286)

    with status 500

    expected value:

    Status 200



*** Request working fine with other headers.


Header --- --- ----
host: randomHost
Accept: */*
User-Agent: random/1.0
X-Signature: randomSignature
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: **Not** closing this question as a duplicate of the canonical NPE question because this appears to be a result of a bug inside Vert.x (at an absolute minimum, a failure to validate configuration during startup).

Comment: The canonical NPE *doesn't* apply here, because this is quite clearly not a bug in your code (at least primarily). I'm leaving it for a Vert.x expert to address. Please update your question with your exact versions of all Vert.x packages and your JRE.

Comment: Vert.x Version 3.3.3

Comment: can you add the client request headers? Vertx streams uploads to the disk under certain circumstances and it might be confused by ambiguous headers

Comment: Added at the end of the question.

Comment: Note: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names are written in PascalCase. `myHandler` should be `MyHandler`.